# Docker Error: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: exec: line 9: /usr/bin/supervisord: not found

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket

I have docker image **websocket.dockerfile** like below

```
FROM php:7-cli-alpine

RUN apk --update add supervisor

RUN rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /var/www

COPY websockets.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/php", "/var/www/html/websocket-service/artisan", "websockets:serve"]
```

below **websocket.conf**

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:websockets]
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/websocket-service/artisan websockets:serve
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=laravel-echo
```

Below **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
   websockets:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: websocket.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 6001:6001
```

When i run docker-compose up command it shows me below error and doesn't run ENTRYPOINT command. I want it to run that command.

```
websockets_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: exec: line 9: /usr/bin/supervisord: not found
websocket-service_websockets_1 exited with code 127
```

What is wrong i have done?

Comment: To debug it try to remove your entrypoints, then ssh into the container and inspect what is installed and what is not. Maybe the apk install went wrong, or supervisor is located somewhere else. `docker-compose exec websockets bash`

Comment: also, have you tried switching the parameter order on apk? so `apk --update add  supervisor` becomes `apk add --update supervisor`

Comment: It works with other things.

Comment: The error doesn't match what you've provided. The entrypoint should be `/usr/bin/php` while the error shows `/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint`.

Comment: Try check CLRF in your entry script